# Create Entry within Spring throws Unsupported Media Type

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring

i am currently learning Spring and i want to use it in my React Application.

I have created multiple Entities and now i want to create a new Entry within my React Application.

My User Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

public User() {}
```

My Picklist Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "picklists")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Picklists {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "createdbyid", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User createdById;
@Column(name = "label")
private String label;

public Picklists() {

}
```

My Picklist Controller:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class PicklistsController {

    private final PicklistRepository picklistRepository;

    public PicklistsController(PicklistRepository picklistRepository) {
        this.picklistRepository = picklistRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/createPicklistEntry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Picklists createObjectField(@RequestBody Picklists picklists) {
        return this.picklistRepository.save(picklists);
    }

}
```

I have tested to create a new Entity using Postman. This is my Request Body i'm sending:

```
{
    "createdById": {
        "userId": 1
    },
    "label": "Test"
}
```

But when sending the POST Request, i'm getting the following Error:
https://pastebin.com/ZbpjXF32

POST Method in React:

```
export const createItem = (url, item) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.post(url, item, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                resolve(response.data)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                reject(error)
            });
    })
}
```

useState:

const [selectedPicklist, setSelectedPicklist] = useState({
label: '',
createdById: {
userId: 1
}
});

Calling the POST Method:

```
createItem('http://localhost:8080/api/v1/createPicklistEntry', selectedPicklist)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(`Created Picklist: ${selectedPicklist}`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Comment: Can you post the controller and JS code too

Comment: I have updated my original Post.

Comment: I don’t see the controller though in Spring side can you post that too

Answer (score 0):

Add below attribute within @RequeatMapping annotation.

```
consumess = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
```

Don't follow repository initialization like above and remove the constructor. Do the Autowire.

```
@Autowired
private final PicklistRepository picklistRepository;
```

Comment: I tried your Solution, but i still get the following Error:
Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type, class com.simagdo.crmAPI.objects.picklists.Picklists]]: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Multiple back-reference properties with name 'defaultReference'
Note: I have multiple References in my Picklist Entity, whereas i only showed one in the original Post because i thought it is enough to post one.

Comment: Then add  JsonManagedReference on parent class with oneToMany place and add JsonBackReference on child entity at ManyToOne place.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I don't really understand what to add where.

Comment: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/json-managed-reference.html

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion

Answer (score 0):

I think your Controller can be simply.

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class PicklistsController {

    private final PicklistRepository picklistRepository;

    public PicklistsController(PicklistRepository picklistRepository) {
        
        this.picklistRepository = picklistRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/createPicklistEntry")
    public Picklists createObjectField(@RequestBody Picklists picklists) {

        return this.picklistRepository.save(picklists);
    }
}
```

Then in your frontend I think it can be simply.

```
export const createItem = (url, item) => {
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    
        axios.post(url, item)
             .then(response => {

                 resolve(response.data);
             })
             .catch(error => {
 
                 reject(error);
             });
    });
}
```

You should not need to pass any headers for JSON stuff. You can also use `async/await` rather than `Promise` if you prefer.